# Let $R$ be an equivalence relation: How many elements are in $R$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Let $R\subset X\times X, |X|=30$. Supposing there are only 3 distinct equivalence classes and all of these have the same amount of elements, find $|R|$.

I didn't get very far on this, I thought that because $R$ is reflexive all the pairs of the form $(a,a): a\in X$ are in $R$. Also that $3\mid |R|$ and that $30\leq |R| \leq 30^2=|X^2|$.

Do I have any more information I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 3):

Each equivalence class has ten elements, and for any $a,b$ within the same equivalence class, $R$ has the element $(a,b)$. Hence each class contributes $10\cdot 10$ and ultimately we find that $|R|=300$.

Comment: Why does each equivalence class have 10 elements? Could you elaborate a bit more ? I'm having trouble understanding the whys of most of that, sorry.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: If $A$ is an equivalence class, then $|X|=|A|\cdot3$. What is the size of $A$?

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks Asaf! What about the part that each class contributes $10\cdot 10$? How do I get that answer? This seems pretty easy but I'm kind of lost/tired. Sorry if I'm asking dumb questions.